# Incorrect encoding when initializing database with DataSourceInitializer in Spring Framework

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Framework 4 and Hibernate 4 together with MySQL database. For initializing database with data I use initialization script configured in hibernate.xml file.

Initialization of database goes alright, but in database appears `?` instead of characters with diacritics. For example instead of `Česko` I see `?esko`.

Any ideas?

**database.sql**

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Slovensko'), (2, 'Česko'), (3, 'Poľsko'), (4, 'Maďarsko');
```

**COUNTRY table created by Hibernate**

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_l7qlysdc1xbo69vsmueersr2k` (`NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**database.properties**

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BPM?UseUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

**hibernate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <!-- Database properties file -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure JDBC Connection -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure Hibernate 4 Session Facotry -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="bpm" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialize database -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:/data/database.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="bpm"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. The problem was in connection URL, it should be:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BPM?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```